# Angular DropDown inside Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a better way to populate this select dropdown from a child array win my json result?
The following does not work although it looks formatted correctly to me. Any ideas?
I have a directive that dynamically builds a form within an angularui accordion.
This piece of code below looks to see if the type is a dropdown and then takes the collection results and puts the value/text within the select dropdown.
DDLValue is a json array with the dropdown data I need. I know there is a cleaner way buy I am new to Angular. Please help. Thanks

**I made an example of my problem on PLNKR
http://plnkr.co/edit/R4auh433JG1GuiYppExm?p=preview**

```
app.directive('ngFormfield', function () {
        return {
 link: function (scope, element, attrs) {               
    if (scope.record.Type == 'Dropdown') {
                element.html('<select class="btn btn-default dropdown" ng-model=' + scope.record.DDLValue.value + ' ng-options="obj.value as obj.text for obj in ' + scope.record.DDLValue + '"></select>');
    }
}
```

JSON

```
records:[{
         {
           RecordId 91,
           Type:"Dropdown',
            "Label": "Favoritebook",
            "DDLValue": "[{ 'value': '1', 'text': 'HarryPotter' }, 
                          { 'value': '2', 'text': 'StarGate' }]"
        }]
```

Comment: please create s jsfiddle or plunker for this

Comment: Here is a plunkr that works. The only thing not working is populating the drop down. Any help is appreciated.http://plnkr.co/edit/R4auh433JG1GuiYppExm?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You must recompile the elements to the DOM. Angular does not know about the new elements loaded into the page until you integrate the new elements back into Angular's application.
Example in Plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/R4auh433JG1GuiYppExm?p=preview

```
 app.directive('ngFormfield', function ($compile) {
            return {
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                    if (scope.record.Type == 'Label') {

                        element.html('<label type="label" ng-model="record.DDLValue.value"/>' + scope.record.Label + '</label>');

                    }
                    else if (scope.record.Type == 'Text') {
                        element.html('<td colspan="8">'+scope.record.Label + ': <input type="text" name="fname"></td>');
                    }
                    else if (scope.record.Type == 'Dropdown') {
                        element.html('<td colspan="8"><select class="btn btn-default dropdown" ng-model=record.DDLValue.value ng-options="obj.value as obj.text for obj in record.DDLValue"></select></td>');
                    }

              fix--->    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                }
            }
        });
```